# Convert MGA to Lat Long

Tags: coordinate-system, australia

Converting the below coordinators to degrees minutes seconds so I can plot on Google Earth. The location willbe around Gympie Queensland Australia, most likely north...

AMG 4612 70065

The source data is from the book https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://gsq-horizon.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/QDEX/39277/cr_39277_2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi4qqm3r676AhWzX3wKHTxCABkQFnoECAwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3-CE9SgdTs1DqFzw5sRd8w
Refer to page 53.
Reading another source suggests the location is 'just north of Gympie'

Mapsheet and explanation is in open acces available from
https://geoscience.data.qld.gov.au/data/map-collection/mr000246

Gympie Special. Map type: Geology. Map subtype: Surface. Map medium: Paper. Coverage: Special. Map sheet reference: GYMPIE:9445,LAGUNA BAY:9545. Map scale: 1:100000. Map series type: 1:100000. Map version: First Edition

Coordinate reference from map: AMG zone 56

Comment: Where did you get this? Any documentation or metadata? Is it from a map page?

Comment: Please add more details - AMG/MGA? - what is the source data?

Comment: Hello, it is from a book I am reading, here is the link.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://gsq-horizon.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/QDEX/39277/cr_39277_2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi4qqm3r676AhWzX3wKHTxCABkQFnoECAwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3-CE9SgdTs1DqFzw5sRd8w

Comment: You will see page 1 talks about the location, then further down on page 53 under gemstones is the bit I am looking for

Comment: "AMG is the Australian Map Grid, as applied to either AGD66 or AGD84, in a projected
coordinate system (as opposed to a geographic coordinate system). AMG uses Cartesian
coordinates (easting, northings) rather than latitude/ longitude." [source](https://www.dcceew.gov.au/sites/default/files/documents/ir473.pdf)
Which is used [depends on location](https://parametricmonkey.com/2020/04/08/understanding-australias-coordinate-systems/)

Comment: These AMG coordinates are truncated UTM coordinates for AMG zone 56, the full coordinates are 461200, 7006500, using tool-online.com/en/coordinate-converter.php assuming AGD84 datum for the map gives WGS84 152.60978470 E, 27.06155492 S

Comment: .... which is strange as this is south of mapheet Gympie, either this coordinate really  refers to a location outside the map or there is a typo in coordinate 70065.

Comment: Thank you Hans, that is what was confusing me.  I have emailed to the author to request clarification.